# Mysql 24 hour period group by hour

Tags: mysql, time

I am trying to group the last 24 Hours of analytics by hour

this is my table.

[image]

I can run this query and it will group with a total.

```
SELECT SUM( watched_time ) AS total
FROM wp_video_analytics_time 
WHERE created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY HOUR(created)
```

It outputs.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to output the date alongside the grouped column.

Something like this.

[image]

I am trying to do this so I can add this data to a Google chart and display the time watched in the last 24 hours.

Ideally I would like the whole 24 hours with zero values if there is no data. But any help would be appreciated at this stage.

Ok so I have the hours working.

```
SELECT SUM( watched_time ) AS total, HOUR(created) AS hours
FROM wp_video_analytics_time 
WHERE created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY HOUR(created)
```

Can anyone explain how to add the zero values for hours that dont have any data this does not seem simple.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *how to add the zero values for hours that dont have any data* Use generated hours table (statically or in CTE) as a base datasource.